# How to use pd.interpolate fill the gap with only one missing data

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a time series data for air pollution with several missing gaps like this:

```
Date             AMB_TEMP      CO         PM10       PM2.5
2010-01-01 0         8         10         ...          15
2010-01-01 1         10        15         ...          20
...
2010-01-02 0                   5          ...           
2010-01-02 1                              ...          20
...
2010-01-03 1         4         13         ...          34
```

To specify, here's the data link: [shorturl.at/blBN1](http://shorturl.at/blBN1)

The gaps were composed of several consecutive or inconsecutive NAs, and there are some helpful statistics done by R like:

1. Length of time series: **87648**
2. Number of Missing Values:**746**
3. Percentage of Missing Values: **0.85 %**
4. Number of Gaps: **136**
5. Average Gap Size: **5.485294**
6. Longest NA gap (series of consecutive NAs):  **32**
7. Most frequent gap size (series of consecutive NA series): **1(occurring 50 times)**

Generally if I use the `df.interpolate(limit=1)`,
gaps with more than one missing will be interpolated as well.

So I guess a better way to interpolate the gap with only one missing is to get the gap id.

To do so, I grouped the different size of gap and used the following function:

```py
    cum = df.notna().cumsum()
    cum[cum.duplicated()]
```

and got the result:

```
                       PM2.5
2019-01-09 13:00:00     205
2019-01-10 15:00:00     230
2019-01-10 16:00:00     230
2019-01-16 11:00:00     368
2019-01-23 14:00:00     538
                       ... 
2019-12-02 10:00:00    7971
2019-12-10 09:00:00    8161
2019-12-16 15:00:00    8310
2019-12-24 12:00:00    8498
2019-12-31 10:00:00    8663
```

**How to get the index of each first missing value in each gap like this?**

```
                     PM2.5 gap size
2019-01-09 13:00:00     1
2019-01-10 15:00:00     2
2019-01-16 11:00:00     1
2019-01-23 14:00:00     1
                       ... 
2019-12-02 10:00:00     1
2019-12-10 09:00:00     1
2019-12-16 15:00:00     1
2019-12-24 12:00:00     1
2019-12-31 10:00:00     1
```

but when I used `cum[cum.duplicated()].groupby(cum[cum.duplicated()]).count()` the index would miss.

Are there better solutions to do these?

**OR How to interpolate case by case?**

Anyone can help me?

Comment: are you talking numpy or pandas ?

Comment: @pippo1980 sorry, I guess it's much close to pandas. Already correct it. Thanks!

Comment: @pippo1980 is that clear after? thank you a lot!

Comment: Didn’t have the chance to test it. I am newbie to python don’t know about pandas, just trying to learn too, hope someone better is listening

Comment: not able to reproduce your results to get empty cells for column to me print(data_df.loc[data_df['AMB_TEMP'].isnull(), :]) works

Comment: 20463 lines with at least one gap